# Match last word after /

Tags: regex

so, i have some kind of intern urls: for example "/img/pic/Image1.jpg" or "/pic/Image1.jpg" or just "Image1.jpg", and i need to match this "Image1.jpg" in other words i want to match last character sequence after / or if there are no / than just character sequence. Thank you in advance!

Comment: regex is universal) but it's for javascript regex

Comment: regexes are not universal, there are several flavours with different capabilities. But this Perl regex will do your task: `^(?:.*/)*(.*)$`

Comment: you don't need a regex for this. use your favourite language, split on "/" and then get the last element. Much simpler than crafting regex.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`.*/(.*)` won't work if there are no /s.

`([^/]*)$` should work whether there are or aren't.

Answer (score 11):

Actually you don't need regexp for this.

```
s="this/is/a/test"
s.substr(s.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
=> test
```

and it also works fine for strings without any `/` because then lastIndexOf returns -1.

```
s="hest"
s.substr(s.lastIndexOf("/")+1)
=> hest
```

Answer (score 3):

```
.*/([^/]*)
```

The capturing group matches the last sequence after /.

Comment: You can also do `(.*)/(?!/)` so the last character is not consumed by the regular expression: https://regex101.com/r/YCatho/1

Answer (score 2):

The following expression would do the trick:

```
/([\w\d._-]*)$
```

Or even easier (but i think this has also been posted below before me)

```
([^/]+)$
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple regex that I have tested:

```
\w+(.)\w+$
```

Here is a good site you can test it on: http://rubular.com/

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby You would write

```
([^\/]*)$
```

Regexps in Ruby are quite universal and You can test them live here: http://rubular.com/
By the way: maybe there is other solution that not involves regexps? E.g `File.basenam(path)` (Ruby again)

Edit: **profjim** has posted it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you said in your comments you're using javascript.  You don't actually need a regex for this and I always think it's nice to have an alternative to using regex.

```
var str = "/pic/Image1.jpg";
str.split("/").pop();

// example: 
alert("/pic/Image1.jpg".split("/").pop());     // alerts "Image1.jpg"
alert("Image2.jpg".split("/").pop());          // alerts "Image2.jpg"
```

Comment: `split` would create more string instances than needed plus an array. This could be critical in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Something like .*/(.*)$ (details depend on whether we're talking about Perl, or some other dialect of regular expressions)

First .* matches everything (including slashes). Then there's one slash, then there's .* that matches everything from that slash to the end (that is $).

The * operates greedily from left to right, which means that when you have multiple slashes, the first .* will match all but the last one.